# PCM4202 AGNDL/AGNDR connection

Tags: ground, decoupling-capacitor

First, sorry if my english is not perfect. I have a question regarding AGNDL and AGNDR connectiof for [PCM4202](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=pcm4202&fileType=pdf) . In the data sheet document ( figure 12, page 21) the decoupling caps are not connected to AGNDL nor the AGNDR, . But in the [evaluation module](http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fug%2Fsbau103%2Fsbau103.pdf&ei=VBrIU8iUO4mp7AbZ0oGwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEGWQxfsHYwHn6cWwUAl9lXbiN3rw&bvm=bv.71198958,d.ZGU) (Figure 4 at page 14), these capacitors are tied to ground. Is the schematic from the data sheet( Figure 12) wrong?

I am not so good in electronics and I hope someone will give me the right answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to this:
[image]

Which can be confusing to a neophyte.  In these drawing conventions, if two wires cross and there is NO dot then the wires are NOT connected.

But the drawing is poorly done, the ground connection really should be drawn closer to the package to avoid this confusion.

[image]

These two pictures are electrically equivalent.

and from the eval module.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I refer exactly to this picture. In the evaluation board, the connection between AGNDL or AGNDR and capacitors terminals is well drawn. So, in the above picture, the connections are missing and that is wrong?

Comment: @NumLock the connection is NOT missing, it is just drawn confusingly.  See the second picture above.

Comment: One more little thing:

Comment: If someone draw a schematic like in the first picture and then design a PCB, the terminals of the capacitors will not be connected to pin 2 or pin 27. But if the schematic circuit is drawn like in the second picture, then the ratsnets will show that the terminals need to be connected to pin 2 respectively to pin 27. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, they are exactly the same.  The convention is, that if two wires cross they doNOT connect unless you have a dot.  In fact it is recommended that you _never_ have two wires cross with a dot to avoid that confusion.  However, unless you have experience with that (like your case) it can be very confusing.  In the first picture, the lines do not connect and the ground IS connected to the ground pins without connecting to anything else.  It is a poor drawing.

Comment: It was very confusing. Now it is clear for me! Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

The text in the [PCM4202](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm4202.pdf) manual on page 13 states

> The PCM4202 includes two on-chip voltage references, one each for the
>   Left and Right channels. The V REF L (pin 1) and V REF R (pin 28)
>   outputs correspond to high reference outputs for Left and Right
>   channels, respectively. De-coupling capacitors are connected between
>   each of these pins and the corresponding reference ground pin, either
>   AGNDL (pin 2) for the V REF L output or AGNDR (pin 27) for the V REF R
>   output.

Which makes it clear that there should be a ground connection to the corresponding capacitors.